# I am getting error "Expected Expression" in MongoDB

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

`{ $and: [ { 'username': username } , { 'device_id': { $in: [] } }] }`

I am getting error:

> "Expected Expression" in MongoDB

please let me know how to parse it

Comment: try it ` { 'username': username , 'device_id': { $in: [] } `

Comment: Need to fetch device list as per username for below json -

{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "612fb76f7176d02a44d499e1"
  },
  "username": "admin",
  "device_id": [
    "DT1001",
    "DT1002",
    "DT1003",
    "DT1004",
    "DT1005"
  ]
}

Comment: `db.collection('collection').find({username:"admin"},{device_id:1})`